# Using multiple where clauses to check two tables

Tags: sql, adminer

So I have a sql statement in a php file that is related to a form that gets input from a user. When they enter in a genre though it updates all the records in that column and not the specific one they chose.

The original statement I had that works is this first code but it edits the whole column. So I have been trying out other clauses so it only changes the one with the matching album_id but have not had any luck.
[Sample Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Nto.jpg)

```
$sql = "UPDATE album 
    SET genre_id = (SELECT genre_id
    FROM genre
    WHERE genreName='" . $_POST['lstGenre'] . "'
    )";
```

Above is what I started with and keep going back to.
[Result from code above changes genre in entire column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXx9F.jpg)

```
$sql = "UPDATE album 
    SET genre_id = (SELECT genre_id
    FROM genre
    WHERE genreName='" . $_POST['lstGenre'] . "'
    )
        FROM album
        WHERE album_id='" . $_POST['album_id'] . "'";
```

That is one version I tried but then it does not update anything.
This is what I am looking for:
[Different genre for each case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qexdr.jpg)

**This works I solved it:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE album 
        SET genre_id = (SELECT genre_id
        FROM genre
        WHERE genreName='" . $_POST['lstGenre'] . "'
        )
        FROM album
        WHERE album_id='" . $thisAlbum['album_id'] . "'";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you at least explain what is missing instead of just posting that. I have explained the problem. Shown the code that is causing the problem and one of the attempts I have tried to fix the problem.

Comment: Sample table data and the expected result would be a great improvement.

Comment: You should read about [SQL injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using!

Answer (score 0):

Almost, but `Update ... From ... Where ...` is not valid, you just have to get rid of the From section in the second part. It should be something like

```
$sql = "UPDATE album 
SET genre_id = (SELECT genre_id
    FROM genre
    WHERE genreName='" . $_POST['lstGenre'] . "'
)
WHERE album_id='" . $_POST['album_id'] . "'";
```

EDIT: Also, sub-queries like that need to only pull one row. Make sure there are not multiple rows in the genre table that match the provided genreName. Though you should be getting a sql error if that were the case.

Comment: are you getting a sql error? have you tried printing the $sql string to make sure the sql statement actually looks how you expect it to?

Comment: No, I am not getting an error. I have printed it and it shows it is grabbing all the right values but it is not actually updating the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
UPDATE album a       
    SET genre_id = (SELECT g.genre_id
                    FROM genre g
                    WHERE g.genreName = ?
                   )
    WHERE a.album_id = ?;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for a *parameter*.  You should be using parameters to pass values in to queries, not munging the query string with values.

Comment: So I have learned about prepared statements this week so from now on that is what I will use. I am a student so was not aware of this when you posted the comment.